# Call JavaScript function from Android not working

Tags: javascript, android

I have a Webview in which a user defined website is loaded, then on the press of a button below the WebView a Javascript (from a remote url) is loaded into the page the user is on.

Then a function within this JavaScript should be fired, however it does not seem to be working.

my activity:

```
public class SearchViewer extends SherlockActivity {

    TextView grabit;
    WebView webView;
    ImageView right, left;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @SuppressLint({ "JavascriptInterface", "SetJavaScriptEnabled" })
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.searchviewer);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrowleft);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String url = intent.getStringExtra("URL");
        String name = intent.getStringExtra("Name");
        setTitle(name);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
        grabit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.grabit);
        grabit.setOnClickListener(OnClick_grabit);

        right = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.right);
        left = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.left);

        right.setOnClickListener(OnClick_right);
        left.setOnClickListener(OnClick_left);

    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            break;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);
    }

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);
    }

    private OnClickListener OnClick_grabit = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript: function loadScript(scriptURL) { var scriptElem = document.createElement('SCRIPT'); scriptElem.setAttribute('language', 'JavaScript'); scriptElem.setAttribute('src', scriptURL); document.body.appendChild(scriptElem);} loadScript('http://www.pathtofile.com/javascript.js');");
            webView.loadUrl("javascript: initialize("+1+")");
        }
    };
    private OnClickListener OnClick_right = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            webView.goForward();
        }
    };
    private OnClickListener OnClick_left = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            webView.goBack();
        }
    };
```

When I load the javascript with just

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript: function loadScript(scriptURL) { var scriptElem = document.createElement('SCRIPT'); scriptElem.setAttribute('language', 'JavaScript'); scriptElem.setAttribute('src', scriptURL); document.body.appendChild(scriptElem);} loadScript('http://www.pathtofile.com/javascript.js');");
```

and start the Javascript `initialize()` function within the Javascript file it works fine.
However when I try and do the above two lines

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript: function loadScript(scriptURL) { var scriptElem = document.createElement('SCRIPT'); scriptElem.setAttribute('language', 'JavaScript'); scriptElem.setAttribute('src', scriptURL); document.body.appendChild(scriptElem);} loadScript('http://www.pathtofile.com/javascript.js');");
                webView.loadUrl("javascript: initialize("+1+")");
```

It does not work, how can I go about loading the Javascript and then firing the function from android so I can pass it a value.

I have tried

```
private OnClickListener OnClick_grabit = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript: function loadScript(scriptURL) { var scriptElem = document.createElement('SCRIPT'); scriptElem.setAttribute('language', 'JavaScript'); scriptElem.setAttribute('src', scriptURL); document.body.appendChild(scriptElem);} loadScript('http://www.pmdev.co.uk/dadg-giftgrabber/android/gift-grabber.js');");
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                    webView.loadUrl("javascript: initialize("+1+")");
                }

            });
        }
    };
```

but this does not work

Comment: you have to wait for the first "url" to be loaded before calling it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript: function loadScript(scriptURL) { var scriptElem = document.createElement('SCRIPT'); scriptElem.setAttribute('language', 'JavaScript'); scriptElem.setAttribute('src', scriptURL); document.body.appendChild(scriptElem);} loadScript('http://www.pathtofile.com/javascript.js');initialize("+1+")");
```

Answer (score 0):

Lajos' answer should work, but, if you want your last snippet to work, you'd need to call `setWebViewClient` with the onPageFinished that calls initialize before you actually call the `loadUrl` that loads the script, and even if you do that you should be careful cause you'd be calling your javascript `initialize()` function twice. 
The thing is, loadUrl will produce a call to onPageFinished when it's done loading (even if the url is a `javascript:` url.